# Mapping a database table to ldap (Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition - ODSEE)

Tags: oracle, ldap, directory-server

I'm working with an ODSEE LDAP server for a PBX telephony solution that uses LDAP to store the enterprise directory.

All the enterprise directory data need to be imported daily from an Oracle relational database table.

I have found that for other LDAP Oracle solutions like Oracle Internet Directory there is a quite straightforward method of doing the sync, just mapping the column names to ldap prefixes, like described here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/idmanage.1012/b14085/odip_db004.htm

Do you know if there is any way to do this  in ODSEE?

Thanks.